# Divide and conquer: is part of the efficiency that solving the subproblems is significantly faster than the undivided problem?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I am thinking about QuickSort specifically: each subproblem is about half the size of the main problem -- is it that the subproblems, including the overhead of dividing the main problem and then recombining the results of the solved subproblems, tend to be solved in less than half the time of the main problem?

I understand that solving the subproblems is parallel is also a way that of speeding up the algorithm but most of the discussions of QuickSort don't mention parallelism.

Comment: Consider this: 1) Most quicksort/mergesort implementations are *not* executed in parallel. 2) The Big-O remains the same, regardless. Even if workload is spread, overall work is not reduced.

Comment: if executed in parallel there is no improvement in time? is that what you are saying and if so, how can that be? I think you are saying the overall work is not reduced; but it is clear that if anything can be done in parallel, the speed is increased and parallelism is one thing that D&C offers.

Comment: The *overall work* is not reduced with parallelism (and may be increased). The wall time is less, but the total time (energy) spent is the same. Assuming 100% work can be parallelized (which is note the case here anyway), processing on X units is really no different than processing on 1 unit that is X times as fast: this does not affect the complexity bounds.

Comment: there are obviously cases where speed is valuable.

Comment: Go back to the initial rumination and first comment. That will enable focusing on *why* the time bounds of a merge sort (easier to analyze than a quicksort) is better than a bubble sort. *Big-O is only about limits*, as N approaches infinity. Having a bubble sort “speedier” for a smaller N (or because it is run using more resources) is irrelevant to the bounds. Same goes for a particular merge sort being parallelized or not.

Comment: So, could there be a merge sort implementation that is “speedier”? Yes, even without parallelism. Does this give merge sort it’s “ideal bounds”? No. That’s from the algorithm (time complexity; N -> infinity), not the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you analyze QuickSort you'll find its efficiency is actually a function of the quality of the pivot, and there are always cases which either by bad luck or deliberate maliciousness will run as O(N^2).

But in general, the complexity of a D&C algorithm is due to a combination of the cost of solving the subproblems and of merging the solutions. Coming back to your question, if the cost of merging the solutions is of the order of solving the problem with the naive algorithm, your D&C algorithm will never outperform the naive one.

You can (almost) always work out the complexity of some D&C algorithm using the Master theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

D&C is just a meta-strategy to design  algorithms that may or may not better solve a certain problem; there is no guarantee of "success" i.e. lower complexity, much less lowest one.

QuickSort, for instance, runs in randomized loglinear time and has an acceptable average performance for sorting generic arrays in standard hardware, but is surpassed by other algorithms for specific cases (such as integer arrays) or hardware architectures (such as massively parallel computers).

Comment: A randomized QuickSort is one method to mitigate such doom cases. Most programming languages tend to use a variation of a merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort isn't a good example of divide and conquer, since its primary function of ordering data (< pivot, == pivot, > pivot) is performed before dividing. Once the base case of a partition size == 1 is reached, then all of the elements in that part of the call chain have been ordered.

A typical top down merge sort is a better example, since it does nothing other than push indexes (or pointers) onto the stack via recursive calls, and no merging takes place until two instances of sub-array size of 1 occur. Then the merging is done, following the call chain up and down. However, bottom up merge sort skips all of the recursive generation of indexes, and starts by treating an array of n elements as n sub-arrays of size 1, and starts merging immediately. Top down is mostly used for educational purposed, while most libraries use some hybrid of bottom up merge sort and insertion sort.

Comment: Are you saying that in some D&C, you are getting smaller chunks to operate on which results in less time complexity even without parallelism?

Comment: @releseabe - from the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm) - "A divide-and-conquer algorithm works by recursively breaking down a problem into two or more sub-problems of the same or related type, until these become simple enough to be solved directly. The solutions to the sub-problems are then combined to give a solution to the original problem." So the goal is to simplify the problem rather than reduce time complexity. Typically "simple enough" means a "base case". For top down merge sort, the base case is when division results in a sub-array of size 1.

Comment: that does not mean that they do not reduce time complexity (sometimes) does it? i did of course read the article but wikipedia to me is no authority -- i have seen it be very wrong in some places (not specifically in computer science).

Comment: again, i asked if *sometimes* it reduces time complexity

Comment: @releseabe -  I deleted some prior comments to avoid chat trigger. Generally "simpler" is not faster. Binary search of a sorted array for a specific element value could be considered similar to divide and conquer, since each iteration works on 1/2 of the elements in the prior iteration. Time complexity is O(log(n)) versus a scan which is O(n). In this case, "divide and conquer" is not simpler than a simple scan, but it is faster, so it is not an exception to the generality that "simpler" usually isn't faster.